# How to install nodejs modules in a local app directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm taking a node.js course on `frontendmasters.com`.  In this course, which appears to be at least one or two years old, the instructor creates an application directory called 'express', cds into it, and then runs the command "npm install express".  According to him, since I didn't specify the '-g' option (which would cause npm to install it globally), a node_modules directory should be created inside the express folder.  And when he ran the command on his laptop, that's what happened.  He says this is done so that if, for instance, you had two different apps which needed different versions of express, you could run a different version in each app's directory.  This makes perfect sense.

However, when I ran the 'npm install express' command, I discovered that npm created a $HOME/node_modules/express directory rather than creating that node_modules directory below my express project directory.  When I created a second app, basic2, at the same directory level as basic, I found that I didn't need to re-run the 'npm install express' command as express is still accessible via the $HOME/node_modules directory.  This now means that both apps, basic and basic2 will be using the same version of express which contradicts what the instructor said.

So my question is, how does one install express (or any other module, for that matter) using npm so that the node_modules directory is created locally in one's local app directory (i.e. on a per-app basis) rather than in my $HOME directory?  It appears that something about npm has changed since this video was created.

Comment: Is there a `package.json` file in your home directory? Maybe npm thinks it's the root of your project.

Comment: You need to run `npm init` to create the base of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new folder for the app

```
mkdir my-app
cd my-app
```

Then creating a nodejs app with `npm init` this will ask you several kind of information like the app name version etc... This command will generate package.json

After that you can run the command `npm i --save express` which will add express to the package.json of your app

Comment: please fix: `npm i --save express`  reason is that You're creating `package.json` by calling `npm init` and You've to save dependencies that You use.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I needed to run ```npm init``` before ```npm install```.  I'm not sure why the instructor left that out.